# Correct syntax to reference an azure pipeline variable inside an expression

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a block like the following, where `foo` is a pipeline variable created in AzureDevOps and I want to access the value in my yaml file

```
variables:
  - name: MyVar
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['foo'], 'bar') , eq(parameters.environment, 'xyz')) }}:
     value: abc
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['foo'], 'baz') , eq(parameters.environment, 'pqr')) }}:
     value: def
```

the above doesn't seem to be the correct syntax though, as my variable `MyVar` remains empty. What is the correct syntax? Apart from the one above, I have tried the following without success

```
variables:
  - name: MyVar
    ${{ if and(eq(variables.foo, 'bar') , eq(parameters.environment, 'xyz')) }}:
     value: abc
    ${{ if and(eq(variables.foo, 'baz') , eq(parameters.environment, 'pqr')) }}:
     value: def
```

and

```
variables:
  - name: MyVar
    ${{ if and(eq($(foo), 'bar') , eq(parameters.environment, 'xyz')) }}:
     value: abc
    ${{ if and(eq($(foo), 'baz') , eq(parameters.environment, 'pqr')) }}:
     value: def
```

Comment: Variables defined at runtime are, by definition, runtime variables. You're using compilation-time syntax. You can't use runtime variables in compile-time expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel wrote you are mixing compile-time expressions with run-time expressions.

This is possible to use variables in compile-time expression which is `${{ }}`, but it has to be static variable.

```yaml
variables:
  staticVar: 'my value' # static variable
  compileVar: ${{ variables.staticVar }} # compile time expression
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')] # runtime expression

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{variables.staticVar}} # outputs my value
      echo $(compileVar) # outputs my value
      echo $(isMain) # outputs True
```

Please take a look on [template expression doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-expressions?view=azure-devops)

> Use template expressions to specify how values are dynamically resolved during pipeline initialization. Wrap your template expression inside this syntax: ${{ }}.
>
> Template expressions can expand template parameters, and also variables. You can use parameters to influence how a template is expanded. The parameters object works like the variables object in an expression. Only predefined variables can be used in template expressions.

It could be somehow misleading with [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) which suggest belonging to run-time evaluation:

> Parameters are only available at template parsing time. Parameters are expanded just before the pipeline runs so that values surrounded by ${{ }} are replaced with parameter values. Use variables if you need your values to be more widely available during your pipeline run.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But Nevertheless, it is still not clear to me which type is my variable. It is not defined in the yaml file as in your example, but via the ui where I created the pipeline. I proceeded like this: create a new pipeline, choose the repo, use an already existing yaml file and then create a variable. For my understanding it is a static variable. but i can be wrong. Context why i did it this way: I want to use the same yaml file for multiple pipelines, the only difference is the variable

Comment: If the variable is defined on UI this would be a run-time variable. Only variables defined in YAML file are static.